Intercepting cmd+c on Chrome for Mac (for custom copying) unreliable, what am I doing wrong?
For an internal tool at my job, I'm trying to intercept and override the ctrl/cmd+c shortcut.
Context: the script below is added to an html file exported from my application. Its purpose is to make sure that, when the user copies a piece of text, my custom markup is written to the clipboard exactly as is, without any of the style elements added by Chrome when you copy text normally.
Functionally, I want it to work exactly like ctrl/cmd+c would normally work, so as not to break any of my colleagues' muscle memory workflows. Some of us use Macs, some PCs, but we all use Chrome.
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var selected ='';
  var element = '';
  if ((event.ctrlKey || event.metaKey) && (event.key === 'c' || event.key === 'C')) {
    selected = window.getSelection();
    if (selected != '') {
       var selectedElement = document.createElement('div');
       selectedElement.setAttribute('id','selection');
       for (var i = 0, len = selected.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
          selectedElement.appendChild(selected.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
       }
       document.getElementById('export').appendChild(selectedElement);
       element = document.getElementById('selection');
    } else { element = document.getElementById('export'); }
    navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({
      'text/plain': new Blob([element.innerText], {type: 'text/plain'}),
      'text/html': new Blob([element.innerHTML], {type: 'text/html'})
    })])
  document.getElementById('selection').remove();
  }
});
</script>

A keydown event listener is checking for ctrl/cmd combined with "c"/"C". When triggered, the script first checks if a selection exists. If so, the selected text is cloned and appended to the document to make Chrome render it as a separate div element, then written to the clipboard, then removed again. This may seem like a roundabout way of doing things, but it's the only way I could find to get to the selection's innerText and innerHTML (by temporarily turning the selection into its own div element), and it works.
If nothing is selected, a div element called "export" containing the entire document is written to the clipboard (I figured it would be handy to be able to skip ctrl/cmd+a if you want to copy the entire text).
Anyway, all of that isn't important. My problem is that the script works reliably on Chrome for PC, every time. But when I try it on a Mac, the shortcut seems to slip through about two thirds of the time, i.e., it isn't intercepted and the clipboard contents is what you would get without the script. Really strange: I can hit cmd+c and paste into Clipboard Inspector ten times in a row and the results are unpredictable.
Why would something like this work only some of the time? What am I doing wrong? Is event.metaKey known to be unreliable? Disclaimer: I'm not an experienced coder, be gentle. 

Maybe you should have a look at the copy event? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event This will even catch right click copy etc... It also allows you to cancel the actual copying event with preventDefault() and then add your own copy to clipboard. The docs also contain a simple example.

Whoa... Didn't know about the copy event!
I quickly adapted my code and it works perfectly. I hadn't thought of having to catch right click copying either, so that's an added bonus.
Thank you!!!

Happy to help! Feel free to post your final code as an answer if you want the reputation. Sadly I tried making a snippet but Stack Overflow doesn't allow clipboard in the snippets.

Thanks to somethinghere in the comments for this solution using the copy event and preventDefault()! Works like a charm on both PC and Mac.
<script>
document.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  var selected ='';
  var element = '';
  selected = window.getSelection();
  if (selected != '') {
     var selectedElement = document.createElement('div');
     selectedElement.setAttribute('id','selection');
     for (var i = 0, len = selected.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
        selectedElement.appendChild(selected.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
     }
     document.getElementById('export').appendChild(selectedElement);
     element = document.getElementById('selection');
  } else { element = document.getElementById('export'); }
  navigator.clipboard.write([new ClipboardItem({
    'text/plain': new Blob([element.innerText], {type: 'text/plain'}),
    'text/html': new Blob([element.innerHTML], {type: 'text/html'})
  })])
  document.getElementById('selection').remove();
});
</script>

